# how to invoke unix inside perl

Tags: perl, unix

i am trying to execute following command

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$num_args = $#ARGV + 1;
if ($num_args != 1) {
     print "\nUsage: name.pl srv_name \n";
     exit;
}

$srv_name=$ARGV[0];
#$last_name=$ARGV[1];

if( $srv_name eq "afs" || $srv_name eq "mnp") {
    print "You have entred Service Name=$srv_name\n";
}

$cmd= `sepman -l|grep -e $srv_name\( | wc -l`;

print "cmd= $cmd\n";
```

But getting an error:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `sepman -l|grep -e afs( | wc -l'
```

please help me how to invoke unix command inside perl script

Comment: You should never write Perl code without using `use strict; use warnings;`. Your code does not get better without them, and your errors do not disappear, they are just hidden. Also `my $num_args = @ARGV` can be used to get the count. But a preferable way IMO would be `my $srv_name = shift; if (!$srv_name) { print "Usage.."; exit; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If line 16 is a typo, instead of

```
$cmd= `sepman -l|grep -e $srv_name\( | wc -l`;
```

you should wrote

```
$cmd= `sepman -l|grep -e "$srv_name" | wc -l`;
```

If it's not a typo, then write :

```
$cmd= `sepman -l|grep -e "$srv_name\(" | wc -l`;
```

"Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words